# Frequent GC when trying to use convert Object to byte array

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, weblogic, production-environment

I am using below code to convert an object to byte array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baoS= new ByteArrayOutputStream();        
objectOutputStream ooS = new ObjectOutputStream(baoS);
ooS.writeObject(object);        
ooS.flush();        
ooS.close();
return baoS.toByteArray();
```

We are facing frequent GC issues and slowness in production environment. 
We have lot of objects coming at runtime and above code will be invoked to convert the object to byte array. Will this code cause memory leak/ more CPU usage if called frequently?
The object passed is a List. This method has come as a bottleneck when sampling done with JVisualVM.

Comment: Not an answer per se but you might investigate using some other serializing mechanism than the built-in. It's generally disliked and might be on the way out.

Comment: @Erik it probably won't disappear due to backwards compatibility, but you're right about it being a poor solution in these days. With protobuffers and json and other nicer ways to serialize objects.

Comment: What is being done with that byte array?  If you’re writing it to some other OutputStream, I would consider removing all use of ByteArrayOutputStream.  Have the method return void; pass the OutputStream itself as an argument and let the method write the object directly to that.

Comment: The byte array is sent via a JMS queue for asynchronous transaction logging into database as blob.

Comment: Why are you doing the serialization yourself?  Why not just [create an ObjectMessage](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#createObjectMessage-java.io.Serializable-)?

Comment: We are using a framework method in our product to log our transaction details. The framework method is generic which accept a Transaction VO with byte array member variables. This will be logged as blob into table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is adding more heap, if you can. Depending on request volume, this may be cheaper than paying salary to code up a different solution. No code changes, release validation, etc. this way.

> The object passed is a List. This method has come as a bottleneck when sampling done with JVisualVM.

If the list is ginormous, then you have *two* ginormous things on the heap now:

1. the list
2. the byte array version of the list

2 is deceptive. The default buffer in `ByteArrayOutputStream` is 32 bytes. Messages larger than that will result in creating *another* array that's twice is big and copying the data. And if that's not big enough, create *another* array and copy again. etc. etc. That's a lot of work!

Now do that for in parallel for all the requests coming in simultaneously. And then, when all the work is done, you need to reclaim all those ginormous things. That could explain the gc.

Next simple solution is pre-sizing the buffer. If you know 98% of the messages are less than 16k in size, then you can just declare that up front: `new ByteArrayOutputStream(16384);`. Now 98% of all the array copies to grow from 32 bytes up to to 16834 are gone. True, this is inefficient for messages that are actually tiny, but maybe it's a net win.

Or rather than a fixed buffer size, maybe you can guesstimate: `new ByteArrayOutputStream(guessBufferSize(theList));`

Harder solution is you can try easing heap memory pressure by getting things off the heap: write the bytes somewhere else, like say to a temp file on disk and sending the file path to the jms sending widget. Writing to disk makes things slow, but doing so reduces heap thrashing, which makes things fast.